# Defining the type of a List in vb.net at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a class at run time using [typebuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sd82fz7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and after I create this class I want to define its type for a list like

```
dim fooList as new List(of DynamicClassName)
```

Since this doesn't exist at compile time of course it throws an error. When I generate this type I return the type so I can't do something like

```
dim newType = createNewType(foobar)
dim fooList as new List(of getType(newType))
```

How do I assign the type of a List at runtime?

Comment: I've not done this with `TypeBuilder`, but with `CodeDOM` you could have a pretty much empty MustInherit class which the dynamic type inherits from, then add new objects to a `List(Of baseclassType)`.  Otherwise, I think you are left with `List(Of Object)`

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9053440/1070452  it looks like it addresses the same thing generally, perhaps in 2 ways (<T> and a baseclass approach).  It also looks like TypeBuilder is much more complex and convoluted than CodeDOM, FWIW

Comment: Actually, I found FWIW IMO [the difference between CodeDOM and TypeBuilder](http://archive.visualstudiomagazine.com/reports/vslivesf/2004/holmes/) is pretty substantial. CodeDOM can generate code in more languages, but TypeBuilder is more powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `List(Of T)`, but AFAIK you won't be able to cast it to a typed object. I've used the `String` type in the following example.

```
Dim list As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType(New Type() {GetType(String)}))

Debug.WriteLine((TypeOf list Is List(Of String)).ToString())
```

**Output**

> True

So in your case it would look like this:

```
Dim newType = createNewType(foobar)

'Creates a List(Of foobar):
Dim list As IList = Ctype(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType(New Type() {newType})), IList)

'Creates a BindingList(Of foobar):
Dim bindingList As IBindingList = Ctype(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(BindingList(Of )).MakeGenericType(New Type() {newType})), IBindingList)
```

Comment: I imagined the code for this would be long and kinda ugly, but after dealing with TypeBuilder I'm good with this.

Comment: Haha, I know! You will end up with *a lot* of code when using reflection namespace.

Comment: Luckily, their example is perfect for reuse! So happy.

Comment: Sadly, when you add to the bindingList you get "The value "MyRunTimeClassName" is not of type "System.RuntimeType" and cannot be used in this generic collection." I do 'dim newObject = Activator.createinstance(newtype)' and after invoking the properties it breaks on 'bindingList.add(newObject)'.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right type? If `newType` *is* a `Type` then replace `newType.GetType()` with `newType`.

Comment: I ran a test using the code found at the bottom of the [TypeBuilder reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) without any problem.

Comment: Your previous comment was right. I changed that and now it's displaying the class in the listbox. Off to go deal with displaying the columns now.

Comment: I found another source that basically implements the same solution, except with the declarations split into several lines of code (which helped clarify things for me). https://riptutorial.com/vb-net/example/14527/create-an-instance-of-a-generic-type

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but may solve your problem.

Another option would be to use an ArrayList (for which you don't have to assign a type). You can see the details here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is a basic example:

```
Dim anyArrayList as new ArrayList()
anyArrayList.add("Hello")
anyArrayList.add("Testing")
```

Comment: This does solve my initial dilemma, but raises the next question of ["How do I data bind an ArrayList to a ListBox"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277695/databinding-an-arraylist-to-a-listbox-in-vb-net). The only apparent answer of that question is "You should be using a BindingList<T>" which brings me back to my question.

Comment: @user2567273 No, it's not a problem. I've updated my question to include how to create a `BindingList<T>` at runtime.